# Kinect does not turn on / turns off on its own

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the tutorials to understand turtlebot. But it seems like every time the kinect is involved, nothing seems to work.

I keep getting

```
[ INFO] [1323314495.901083262]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

When I restart everything (restart laptop, redo ssh, launch), sometimes I get lucky and hear turtlebot beep and the kinect turns on (red light can be seen from the kinect laser), but this is what I get:

```
[ INFO] [1323314659.192741563]: [/openni_camera] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1323314659.193218090]: [/openni_camera] 1. device on bus 001:11 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00362907481053A'
[ WARN] [1323314659.197118306]: [/openni_camera] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1323314659.255754180]: [/openni_camera] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:11 with serial number 'A00362907481053A'
[ INFO] [1323314659.300121550]: rgb_frame_id = 'kinect_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1323314659.306528300]: depth_frame_id = 'kinect_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1323314660.231673257]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.232153416]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.232556400]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.232883467]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.233230857]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.233678749]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.234094444]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.234581657]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.235145905]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.235744794]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.236493772]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.236933702]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ERROR] [1323314660.237591048]: Cannot load nodelet /pointcloud_throttle for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1323314660.238391290]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.238664998]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ERROR] [1323314660.239578662]: Cannot load nodelet /kinect_laser_narrow for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1323314660.240480382]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1323314660.240773506]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
```

and then I hear turtlebot beep and the kinect goes off again. I thought it was a battery problem, but the dashboard shows the battery is full.

anyone has any idea what else I can do to even complete the tutorials (I managed to reach teleop with no issues)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12263/kinect-does-not-turn-on-/-turns-off-on-its-own/) by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2268 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2011-12-07**:
now the battery bar on the dashboard is going crazy, jumping to >400%, then dropping back to slightly more than 100%. and turtlebot is singing some ominous tone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on ominous sound and jumping battery indicator you have a dead battery.  Make sure the Create is plugged in with the led light throbbing red/orange for at least an hour and try again.  Sometimes the Create does not charge when plugged in.  You have to look for the throbbing red/orange light.  If you don't see that, unplug it, press the power button until you  are confident it's off, then plug it in.  Note: sometimes it appears that the indicator LED turns off even though the robot is still "on" try to turn it on and then immediately off to be confident it's off.  Then it should charge when plugged in.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-12-08**:
I've also noticed that it's easy to not quite insert the battery correctly. Flip your robot over and make sure the battery is firmly snapped into place.